# MongoDB text search finds the long string, but not the shorten string?

Tags: mongodb

In MongoDB 3.6 I have a collection of data with a text search index.  It can find the longer version of a word, but not a shorter version, how can I make it find both versions?

```
db.test.createIndex({name: 'text', description: 'text'});
db.test.insert({name: 'MYREALLYLONGNAME', description: 'MYREALLYLONGNAME'});

db.test.find({$text: {$search: 'MYREALLYLONGNA'}});
> FINDS IT

db.test.find({$text: {$search: 'MYREALLYL'}});
> DOES NOT FIND IT
```

Comment: That it does, "partial text search" is what I should have searched for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would have to be:

```
db.test.find({{$text: {$search: /.*MYREALLYL.*/}})
db.test.find( { name: { $regex: /MYREALLYL/ } } )
```

> note: mongodb uses regular expressions which are more powerful than
>   "LIKE" in sql. With regular expressions you can create any pattern
>   that you imagine.
>
> For more info on regular expressions refer to this link
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/operator/query/regex/